# Rapidly open 1,-1 data file as image

Tags: image, imagemagick

I'm working on a project that produces data files that are square matrices of numbers, either 1 or -1. I need to visualize this as images, and what I do now is using Matlab to open them, the matlab function `imshow` automatically draws those kind of matrices as monochrome black and white images.

Using matlab though is very slow and I was wondering if there was some linux program that I can fastly use from the terminal to do so, like an imagemagick oneliner or something similar.

This is an example of file

```
-1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

And this would be the image

[image]

The actual matrices would be of the order of `128x128`.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show an example of what your expecting? There are many ways to plot a graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trivial to convert your data to "PBM" format, even with a text editor,as I've done here.  Change all of the " 1" to "0", "-1" to "1", and add a one-line header "P1 8 8 1" (substitute the actual width and height for "8 8").  Here's a one-line script matrix2pbm that does that:

```
echo P1 $2 $3 1; sed -e "s/-1/z/g; s/1/0/g; s/z/1/g" $1
```

Run it with

```
./matrix2pbm matrix.txt 8 8 > matrix.pbm
cat matrix.pbm

P1 8 8 1
 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The PBM format is one of the Netpbm image formats [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format]

If you like, you can then use ImageMagick or some other file converter to convert the result into some other format:

```
convert matrix.pbm matrix.png
```

As emcconville commented, you can do both transformations with this one-liner:

```
./matrix2pbm matrix.txt 8 8 | convert pbm:- matrix.png
```

Comment: Great answer! Don't forget `convert ppm:- file.png` for reading Netpmb from stdin.

Comment: Great, that is going to be very helpful! Thank you very much.